# props.history is undefined when using useContext?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I've set up my context and I have a function that runs once the form is submitted `handleSubmit`. When I submit the form, I want the results to be shown on a separate page `dashboard`. I'm using history.push().

My form is wrapped in the `withRouter` HOC.

When I submit the form, I receive "*props.history is undefined*"

I also have another function that is using a `match.params` and I'm getting undefined as well. So I'm assuming it has to do with React Router.

I considered that perhaps my Context file is the one that needs to be wrapped with the `withRouter` HOC, but the file has two exports.

**My Context Provider**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext } from 'react'

const AnimeContext = createContext()

const API = "https://api.jikan.moe/v3"


const AnimeProvider = (props) => {
  const urls = [
    `${API}/top/anime/1/airing`,
    `${API}/top/anime/1/tv`,
    `${API}/top/anime/1/upcoming`,
  ]

  // State for Anime search form
  const [dataItems, setDataItems] = useState([])
  const [animeSearched, setAnimeSearched] = useState(false)

  // Fetch searched Anime
  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    const animeQuery = e.target.elements.anime.value
    const response = await fetch(`${API}/search/anime?q=${animeQuery}&page=1`)
    const animeData = await response.json()

    setDataItems(animeData.results)
    setAnimeSearched(!animeSearched)

    props.history.push('/dashboard')
  }


  return (
    <AnimeContext.Provider value={{
      topTv,
      setTopTv,
      topAiring,
      setTopAiring,
      topUpcoming,
      setTopUpcoming,
      dataItems,
      setDataItems,
      animeSearched,
      setAnimeSearched,
      fetching,
      anime,
      fetchTopAnime,
      fetchAnimeDetails,
      handleSubmit
    }}>
      {props.children}
    </AnimeContext.Provider>
  )
}

export { AnimeProvider, AnimeContext }
```

**My** `SearchForm` **component**

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import AnimeCard from './AnimeCard/AnimeCard';
import { AnimeContext } from '../store/AnimeContext'


const SearchForm = () => {
  const { dataItems, animeSearched, handleSubmit } = useContext(AnimeContext)

  return (
    <div>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Input
          type="text"
          name="anime"
          placeholder="Enter title"
        />
        <FormButton type='submit'>Search</FormButton>
      </ Form>
      {animeSearched
        ?
        <AnimeCard
          dataItems={dataItems}
        />
        : null}
    </div>
  )
}

export default withRouter(SearchForm)
```

Comment: from where you are calling your AnimeProvider?

Comment: @Dave.Q have a look at my answer

Comment: you can wrap `AnimeProvider` with `withRouter`

Comment: @PrakashKarena I'm calling it within my App.js file. It is at the top level wrapping my ```Router```.

Answer (score 3):

you can always use `useHitory` hook everywhere!

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router'
...
const Page = function(props) {
  let history = useHistory();
  ...
  history.push('/')
  ...
}
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me. This was the error I received.  React Hook "useHistory" is called in function "page" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function

Comment: @Dave.Q please try to capitalize 'page', sorry for this silly mistake!

Comment: I tried that, but I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

In react-router, you would get `history` from `props` if any component is rendered as a child or Route or from an ancestor that is renderd form Route and it passed the Router `props` to it. However it is not receiving Router `props`, i suggest try this one

You can use `Redirect` from `react-router-dom`

```
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);
```

Now set the vlue of `redirect` to true where ever you want

```
setRedirect(true);
```

like in your case

```
async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    const animeQuery = e.target.elements.anime.value
    const response = await fetch(`${API}/search/anime?q=${animeQuery}&page=1`)
    const animeData = await response.json()

    setDataItems(animeData.results)
    setAnimeSearched(!animeSearched)

    setRedirect(true);
  }
```

Now you can use the following for the `Redirection` in `return` function like so

```
if(redirect) {
  return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
 } else {
  return (
     <Your-Component />
 )
```

Comment: This didn't work for me either. It said "dataItems" is undefined. Here's the [link](https://github.com/dvlprdave/AniPlex) to my repo.